# Axios is not a function error, how to resolve?

Tags: reactjs, axios

i am trying to resolve this issue but failing. Please help me:

[image]

- I have tried reinstalling using 'npm install axios', did not work.
- changed the axios version to 1.1.2 (goes back to 1.6.7 somehow)
- using : const axios = require("axios").default

  ```
  const sendFile = async () => {
  if (image) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", selectedFile);
    let res = await axios({    ## here I am getting the error
      method: "post",
      url: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
      data: formData,
    });
    if (res.status === 200) {
      setData(res.data);
    }
    setIsloading(false);
  }
  }
  ```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CKlc.png)

Comment: Post the relevant code that causes this error, along with the message and any other detail directly here.

Comment: Hi @Aishwarya Chougule it is helpful to share the Javascript code in the lines where you are using axios. The error of the message is not enough...

Comment: What about swapping to ES Modules? `const axios = require("axios").default` -> `import axios from 'axios'`

Comment: Hi @evolutionxbox i tried this and now i am getting network error 'Network Error
AxiosError: Network Error
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60088:14)
    at Axios.request (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60540:41)
    at async sendFile (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:269:17)'

Comment: That's good. It means that axios isn't the issue anymore. Please may you make a new question to ask about that error?

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement seems correct with ES6 syntax. This error occurs usually when axios is not initialized properly. Try clearing the node.js cache and running the application again.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

You can post your code snippet for more understanding.

Answer (score 0):

please read the documentation carefully. [Minimal Example](https://axios-http.com/docs/example)

```js
const axios = require("axios").default

// axios.<method> will now provide autocomplete and parameter typings
```

[post_example](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example)

```js
import axios from "axios";

const sendFile = async () => {
  if (image) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", selectedFile);
    let res = await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,formData)
    if (res.status === 200) {
      setData(res.data);
    }
    setIsloading(false);
  }
}
```

[image: post]

**Here is the complete improved version of the code I provided.**

```js
import axios from "axios";

// Function to send a file, assumed to be called within a React component or similar context
const sendFile = async () => {
  // Check if there is an image to send
  if (image) {
    setIsLoading(true); // Assuming setIsLoading updates loading state in the component

    // Create a FormData object to hold the file data
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", selectedFile); // Assuming selectedFile is the file to be sent

    try {
      // Attempt to post the FormData to the specified API endpoint
      let res = await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL, formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      });

      // Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
      if (res.status === 200) {
        setData(res.data); // Assuming setData updates state with the response data
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      // Log any errors to the console and handle them as needed
      console.error("Failed to upload file:", error);
      // Here, you could update state to show an error message in the UI
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting this error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post')'

Comment: Are you in a browser environment? Please use `import axios from 'axios'`.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-axios-with-react/ Can this article help you?

Answer (score -1):

You can tr with

```
let res = await axios.post({    ## here I am getting the error
    url: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
    data: formData,
  });
```

Comment: Getting this error when i do this :

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post')